How can I send QueryParams to a REST API from Quarkus?
I'm trying to consume a REST API, but I'm not sure if the endpoint is being formed with the necessary QueryParams. The API receives three parameters, two of them I have as a constant in Java, and one of them I am going to send as a path param in the Quarkus service, but my external service has to send them as query params.
My external endpoint should be set this way:
http://192.168.37.151:8897/api/customer-subscription/v31/subscription/?type=CED&id=0929853042&status=Active
I can't find a way to know if my service arms it this way.
package com.conecel.qasecurity.config;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@RegisterRestClient(baseUri = "http://192.168.37.151:8897/api/customer-subscription/v31/subscription/")
public interface IRestClient {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response getSubscriptionInfo(@QueryParam("type") String type,
                                 @QueryParam("id") String id,
                                 @QueryParam("status") String status);
}



This is my service:
package com.conecel.qasecurity.service;

import com.conecel.qasecurity.config.IRestClient;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomerSubscriptionService implements ICustomerSubscription {

    private static final String TYPE = "CED";
    private static final String STATUS = "Active";

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    IRestClient restClient;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerSubscriptionService.class);

    @Override
    public Response getSubscriptionInfo(String id) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Invocando a la API externa con ID: {}", id);
            // Formar la URL con los parámetros constantes y el parámetro dinámico
            Response response = restClient.getSubscriptionInfo(TYPE, id, STATUS);
            return Response.status(response.getStatus()).entity(response.getEntity()).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Ocurrió un error al consumir el servicio: {}", e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity("Error interno del servicio").build();
        }
    }
}


And this my controller:
package com.conecel.qasecurity.controller;

import com.conecel.qasecurity.service.CustomerSubscriptionService;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.*;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/api")
public class CustomerSubscriptionController {

    @Inject
    private CustomerSubscriptionService customerSubscriptionService;

    @GET
    @Path("/customer-subscription/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getSubscriptionData(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return customerSubscriptionService.getSubscriptionInfo(id);
    }
}



You can write a test againts IRestClient using Wiremock (https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource):

Start Wiremock and configure it to respond to http://localhost:8897/api/customer-subscription/v31/subscription/?type=CED&id=0929853042&status=Active
Create test class, inject IRestClient, perform a IRestClient#getSubscriptionInfo("CED","0929853042","Active") and test wiremock response is 200 (or any value you returned from wiremock)


You can enable logging for the client like this:
quarkus.rest-client.logging.scope=request-response

See also:
https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#logging-traffic
